# unsigned int* assignment changing the target unsigned int

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, c, pointers

Ok this must be something dumb.  I ran into this when moving some code over and figured I had made a typo or was failing to use the debugger correctly.  As a sanity check I created this test case but it still appears to be failing.

```
    unsigned int  vtxIdx = 0;
    unsigned int* tgtIdx;

    NSLog(@"Init %d", vtxIdx);

    tgtIdx = &vtxIdx;

    NSLog(@"After %d", vtxIdx);

    float* pVtx = new float[1000*3];

    NSLog(@"After more %d", vtxIdx);
```

Output:

```
2011-03-24 09:59:23.494 Game-iOS[] Init 0
2011-03-24 09:59:25.677 Game-iOS[] After 4
2011-03-24 09:59:31.828 Game-iOS[] After more 12
```

Edit:

What initially tipped me off was I was seeing weird values in the XCode variable window.  So I don't think it is an NSLog issue as I see those same value in XCode.  Watching vtxIdx in the debugger it appears to increase by 4 with each instruction.

All of this code is in an .mm files if that matters.

Comment: Looks to be more of a general C pointer question, so I added the tags.

Comment: @BoltClock It's actually (Objective-)C++ -- note the `new []` operator in use.

Comment: @TurqMage shouldn't you use `%ud` since these are `unsigned int`s?

Comment: Well I know it doesn't happen when I compile this code is other C compilers :)  I don't know enough about Objective C to know weather its C or C++.  The new[] doesn't seem to matter though, that just happen to be my next line of code.

Comment: Looks like a typical `CANTHAPPEN` caused by a buffer overrun elsewhere in the program. Is there any other code running in between the `NSLog` statements?

Comment: @Richard: Thanks, you're right. Approved your retag :)

Comment: I am not sure %ud is a thing... NSLog(@"Init %ud", vtxIdx); ...[] Init 0d.  %u gives the same result as %d in this case.

Comment: @larsmans  There is no other code.  This is test code I wrote the executes right at the start of the program.  The debugger shows the same values.

Comment: @larsmans yes it was at -Os, I turned it off did a full clean and rebuild and the results were the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second output statement, do you get the same thing if you print the values of both `vtxIdx` and `*tgtIdx`?

Does anything change if you initialize `tgtIdx = NULL;`?

If you run each `NSLog` function twice in a row with the exact same arguments, do they output the same thing each time?

You mentioned a debugger in your question.  What did you see when you single-stepped through this program?

**Edit:**
A few more ideas.

What happens if you comment out the `tgtIdx = &vtxIdx;` line?

What happens if you add the line `unsigned int dummy;` before your existing variable declarations?

Since something seems to be changing the variable behind your back, my first thoughts are a memory corruption issue (some other code is writing over your variable unintentionally) or a linkage problem (the linker saw your variable and another variable with the same name, thought they were the same object, and merged them together).  Adding the dummy variable declaration should help indicate if the problem is a memory corruption problem, and renaming the variables should test for any possible name resolution conflicts.

Comment: Also, does anything change if you make `vtxIdx` a `const`?

Comment: Setting it to null didn't help, I do get the same values for bot vtxIdx and tgtIdx.  I added more info about what I was seeing in the debugger above.

Comment: @bta Spoke too soon.. :)  Making it const moved the problem.  It fixed it for that instance but it just happened at my next int* instead.

Comment: did you do this suggestion "If you run each NSLog function twice in a row with the exact same arguments, do they output the same thing each time?"

Comment: @steabert I do not, the vtxIdx appears to be increasing with each instruction by 4

Comment: @bta Looks like it may be the target that was having the problem.  Changing the name of vtxIdx did nothing but changing the name of tgtIdx fixed the problem.  When I change it back or set any other int pointer to be tgtIdx the issue re-occurs.  Sounds like you are right, I'll let you know if I figure out what caused it.